# is this a good way to play audio in openal using sndfile C++

Tags: c++, openal, libsndfile

I want to play audio while a game is running (and also inside when the game is running)

is this a good way to play a sound in openal?

is opening new threads the best way to do this? (would this cause lag if there are too many threads running at once?)

CODE for a simple audio function (threaded):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <AL/alut.h>
#include <sndfile.h>

//using namespace std;

void playSound(const std::string &file) 
{

    alutInit(NULL, NULL);
    ALuint buffer, source;

    SNDFILE* sndfile;
    SF_INFO sndinfo;
    sndfile = sf_open(file.c_str(), SFM_READ, &sndinfo);
    

    int samples = sndinfo.channels * sndinfo.frames;
    int format = (sndinfo.channels == 1) ? AL_FORMAT_MONO16 : AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;
    short* bufferData = new short[samples];
    sf_read_short(sndfile, bufferData, samples);
    sf_close(sndfile);
    alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    alBufferData(buffer, format, bufferData, samples * sizeof(short), sndinfo.samplerate);
    delete[] bufferData;
    
    alGenSources(1, &source);
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
    
    alSourcePlay(source);
    
    ALint state;
    do {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    } while (state != AL_STOPPED);
    
    alDeleteSources(1, &source);
    alDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);
    alutExit();
}

void playsound(std::string file) 
{
    std::thread sound(playSound, file);
    sound.detach();
}

int main() 
{
    playsound("test.wav");

    while (true)
    {
        //the game code would go here ...
    }
    
    alutExit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does anybody know any better methods?